# LocalDB doesn't work correctly

Tags: sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2012, localdb

when I don't see my databases in `LocalDB`, Is there any service to Start?
I am using SQL Management Studio 2008 and my local instance works correctly but I don't know what's happening to `LocalDB`.
status both of them in `Object Explorer`

[image]

Comment: try to reconnect the LocalDB, and is there any error on event viewer?

Comment: I've tried but problem exists